# integrate Office 365 authentication into asp.mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, office365

I have a webapplication that implements the authentication with azure ad. This works very well with our own azure ad.

But how is it possible to allow other users to sign in into our application?
I don not want to manially assign the users to our active directory for this.

I want a functionality like the auth login like tippsweet.de

how does this work?

Answer (score 1):

We can build the multiple-tenant app to enable the app for the users on other tenants of any organization on Azure AD.

We can enable the 'multiple-tenant' option on the Azure portal like figure below:
[image]

And below are two helpful articles about developing multiple-tenant app integrate with Azure AD:

[Build a multi-tenant SaaS web application using Azure AD & OpenID Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect/)

[Integrating applications with Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/)